# Retrieve TSX intra-day quote from Alphavantage

Tags: alpha-vantage

I've been able to get the daily quote for TSX marketing using this endpoint, and it has been working perfectly.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TSX:BTO&apikey={{key}}

But when I try to get intraday data (60 minutes) with the following request, it doesn't work.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&interval=60min&symbol=TSX:BTO&apikey={{key}}

RESPONSE

```
{
Error Message: "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY."
}
```

Is this because they don't offer intraday data for TSX or did I do anything wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `symbol=BTO.TO` in your URL for both

Longer explanation:
There are a number of different methods for mapping tickers - generally the best method is:
`symbol.exchange`

See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol) for more information

Comment: Any clue if it's possible to access to tsx venture.. ?

Comment: At the moment, I don't think tsx is supported anymore